# How to check if the string contains specific word?

Tags: react-native

I am implementing qr code scanner in the app. I need to check the value appended in the qr code. For ex if the value has "test://i" then show success else fail. Please help to resolve this. I am using expo.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use includes method this will return true if the data has the specific characters else it will return false
Eg:

```
check() {

  var data = "ex if the value has test://i then show success else fail";
  var value = str.includes("test://i");
  return value
})
```